# How to create search index with DSE search 6.8

Tags: search, datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have been working with Datastax 6.7 for a couple of months now. Creating search index with the classic graph requires you create schema.xml and Solrconfig.xml through solr admin, which works fine. But when i upgraded to DSE 6.8, I need to create the search index using Datastax Studio 6.8. I have been able to create VertexLabels, materializedView and secondaryIndex. But i am unable to create a search index.

This is my code to create a search index,

```
  schema.vertexLabel('location').
  searchIndex().
  ifNotExists().
  by('geo_point').
  waitForIndex(3000).
  create()
```

This is the error i get,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create search index for vertex label 'location' in graph 'food_cql'. RELOAD or REBUILD failed for search index on 'food_cql.location'. Failed to reload search index food_cql.location because: No resource solrconfig.xml for core food_cql.location, did you miss to upload it?
```

Comment: Could you post your vertex schema for the label `location`? I've been able to create the search index through Studio without issue, using your syntax. Here is my schema after the index was created: `schema.vertexLabel('location').ifNotExists().partitionBy('locationKey', Varchar).property('geo_point', Point).create();
schema.vertexLabel('location').searchIndex().ifNotExists().by('locationKey').asString().by('geo_point').create()`

Comment: My problem actually lies in reloading the core. I am unable to reload the core once I upload the schema.xml and SolrConfig.xml. Do you have graph and search workload enabled on your DC? I thought we need to upload these 2 files if we need to use Solr queries in datastax. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: The schema.xml and solrconfig.xml are automatically created when we create the search index through the Gremlin schema API, there is no need to create and upload them first.

Comment: Thank you bswynn. I have been able to create the core, search index and also able to make queries using CQL and Solr Admin.

Comment: @bswynn would you happen to have any information in regard to making spatial parameter, facet fields, facet pivots and filterquery(fq) using Gremlin?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create a graph core and search index successfully using these commands.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS geo WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geo.states (
state text,
fips int,
pop  int,
geo   text,
solr_query text,
PRIMARY KEY (state)
)WITH VERTEX LABEL states_label;
```

you'll need to specify the schema and Solr configuration file like this on a Search node:

```
dsetool create_core ks_name.table_name schema=/path/to/schema.xml solrconfig=/path/to/solrconfig.xml
```

You can run these commands to check that they've been uploaded:

```
dsetool get_core_schema

dsetool get_core_config
```

You can run this command to check the status of the cores:

```
dsetool core_indexing_status -all
```

Insert data,

```
INSERT INTO geo.states (state, fips, geo, pop) VALUES ('Idahonew',60, 'POLYGON ((-116.04751 49.000239, -116.04751 47.976051, -115.724371 47.696727))', 3594);
```

Run your queries like this to test:

```
select * FROM geo.states

g.V().hasLabel('states_label')
```